# Floating Voltage to Bias a P-Channel Mosfet without Exceeding Source-Gate Max Voltage

Tags: mosfet, zener

I'm not sure if this is what you'd call "floating voltage" or not.  I'm lacking on some terminology so bear with me.  Here's the circuit with explanation below:

[image]

The premise of the circuit is this:  I want to power L1 coil with square pulses.  You can see I've got a freewheeling diode to handle the back emf field collapse to protect the circuitry.

From previous experiments and talking to others on here, I learned that using an N-channel mosfet on the high side of the coil like this doesn't work because the large negative voltage during the back emf coil collapse puts negative voltage on the mosfet source which causes the gate (at zero volts) to turn on while the field is collapsing.

I experimented with BJTs and they make it easy to fix the problem, but they also get hot.  I really want to use mosfets for the ability to pass a lot of current with minimal resistance.  So I've switched to a P-channel mosfet in the circuit shown.  This seems pretty simple but I'm adding a level of complexity.

I want to have arbitrarily high voltage in the main circuit -- 80volts shown here but it could be more or less.  Since the voltage is prone to change in use conditions, the circuit design must be agnostic to the actual main power voltage .  In the 80 volt example shown, since the p-channel mosfet requires 80volts at the gate to turn it off, I have added a small resistor network to supply the required voltage from the power src.  You can see I'm using a 555 and some BJT's to pull down the gate voltage to turn it on.

Now the tricky part.  From my understanding, I can't drop the mosfet gate all the way to 0V because that would make an 80volt difference between the Source and the Gate which would destroy it.  I need to make sure the gate drops to about 12 volts less than the Source but drops no further.  THe solution I've come up with is to add a 12 volt zener diode and adjust the resistances accordingly so once the gate starts to become more than 12 volts less than the source, the diode will reverse bias and bring the gate back up.  It should stay right around 68volts if the power supply is 80 volts -- as long as the BJT is biased on anyway.  Once the BJT turns off, the gate will recover to 80 volts and shut off the mosfet.

So my question is simply this:  Am I doing this right?  Am I over-engineering it or perhaps doing something wrong?  Let me know.  Thanks!

- Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a better way to drive a high-side P-channel MOSFET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhpwqe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the BJT Q1 is a current sink; the current value is the control voltage divided by R2. If your control circuit puts out 12V, the current will be 12 mA.

This current will create a voltage drop across R1 as well, and if you happen to make the two resistors equal, this voltage drop will be essentially equal to the control voltage supply (minus the V<sub>BE</sub> drop of Q1). Or you can make the resistors different in order to get a particular relationship.

You need to be aware of two things: The current level that you set will have some bearing on how fast the MOSFET M1 switches; higher current means faster switching. However, keep in mind that Q1 has a lot of voltage across it. When off, it has the full high voltage supply across it. And even when switched on, it has the high voltage minus 2× the control voltage across it. This means that it will be dissipating power equal to that voltage drop times the current when on.

Comment: Dave, for all intensive purposes, this is almost exactly the same circuit I showed.  I understand everything you're saying.  But I thought that you will damage the FET if you let the gate drop too far below the Source.... Is that not the case???  If the Source is 80 volts and I pull the gate all the way to 0 volts, it won't break the thing?  The only significant difference in my circuit is that I made adjustments to add the zener diode so that I could control the voltage spread between the Source and Gate.  That's the point of my question.  Is that totally unnecessary?

Comment: No, as I explained, this circuit does **not** pull the gate all the way to ground. The gate-source voltage across the MOSFET is controlled by the specific current that the BJT draws, multiplied by R1. Most of the voltage appears across Q1.

Comment: (BTW, the phrase is "all intents and purposes", not "all intensive purposes".)

Comment: (BTW, the phrase is "all intents and purposes", not "all intensive purposes".)  LOL :) Thanks.

Yes, I see what you're talking about now.  I didn't recognize it can be done this way, but now it makes sense.  Thanks, Dave.  Much appreciated.  Very simple and clever.  But does it mean I need to compute the resistance, current, and voltage drop specifically for the 80volts?  If I change the 80volts to 60volts, then I'll have to change the other values won't I?

Comment: Actually, no. The voltage that appears at the MOSFET gate is simply the control voltage * R1 / R2. The high-voltage supply value doesn't matter; whatever voltage is left over appears across Q1.

Comment: gate voltage is "control voltage * r1 / r2."  That puzzles me.  If the control voltage is 12 volts, that means 12 volts appear at the gate since you have 12 * 1000 / 1000.  But if the main power is 80 volts, then wouldn't we want 68 volts to appear at the gate?

Comment: Sorry. When I say "gate voltage", I mean \$V_{GS}\$, not the gate voltage measured from ground.

Comment: It's ok.  If I were more experienced/knowledgeable, I would have known to figure out what you meant.   So the 1kOhm resistors are somewhat arbitrary.  The math for V_GS works out to be the same voltage regardless if a pair of 100Ohm or 100Kohm resistors are used.  I just need to pick a value that sets a reasonable current to switch the FET fast enough.

Comment: Dave, I really don't understand how this is floating.  And it looks like you made two conflicting statements: "The gate-source voltage across the MOSFET is controlled by the specific current that the BJT draws, multiplied by R1. Most of the voltage appears across Q1."  That makes perfect sense because it's basically acting like a simple voltage divider.  But you just said the specific current is impacting the voltage which means if you change the bias on the BJT gate, you'll change the gate voltage on the mosfet.

Comment: Yes, both statements are correct. The voltage on the base of the BJT directly controls its collector current. And the collector current directly controls the voltage that appears across R1. In this mode of operation, the collector-emitter voltage across Q1 can vary over a wide range with no change in the collector current.